# Popup window and on close return the value to main page

Tags: cakephp

As my form includes many actions I want to call a popup window to do some actions.
But after the submission of the popup window. I have to replace a div in parent window.
    1)How can I call a popup window which is modal?

2)How can the parent window know the child window is closed? (so that I can replace the div with new data)
  Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jquery modal window shown in this [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

While using the modal window in the link you can see that there is an `event` function called `beforeClose`. In this event, you can use callback function to update the div in the parent window.